# kubectl on windows is throwing error You must be logged in to the server

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I installed minikube on my windows laptop and everything was fine, but when I tried to run `kubectl get pod` or any other kubectl commands I am getting this message:

```
kubectl get pod
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

I do not know what am I doing wrong even though I added the credentials to my configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: C:\Users\robert\.minikube\ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.99.100:8443
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    as-user-extra: {}
    client-certificate: C:\Users\robert\.minikube\client.crt
    client-key: C:\Users\robert\.minikube\client.key
```

### minikube info

```
minikube version
minikube version: v0.25.1
```

### minikube upgrade

```
minikube version: v0.25.2
```

### Kubernetes info

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.6", GitCommit:"9f8ebd171479bec0ada837d7ee641dec2f8c6dd1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-21T15:21:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

### minikube directories and files

```
    Directory: C:\Users\robert\.minikube


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        3/22/2018   1:40 PM                addons
d-----        3/22/2018   1:40 PM                cache
d-----        3/22/2018   1:40 PM                certs
d-----        3/22/2018   1:47 PM                config
d-----        3/22/2018   1:40 PM                files
d-----        3/22/2018   1:40 PM                logs
d-----        3/22/2018   9:42 PM                machines
d-----        3/22/2018   2:32 PM                profiles
-a----        3/22/2018  10:56 PM           1298 apiserver.crt
-a----        3/22/2018  10:56 PM           1679 apiserver.key
-a----        3/22/2018   2:33 PM           1066 ca.crt
-a----        3/22/2018   2:33 PM           1675 ca.key
-ar---        3/22/2018  10:55 PM           1054 ca.pem
-ar---        3/22/2018  10:55 PM           1094 cert.pem
-a----        3/22/2018  10:56 PM           1103 client.crt
-a----        3/22/2018  10:56 PM           1675 client.key
-ar---        3/22/2018  10:55 PM           1679 key.pem
-a----        3/22/2018   7:29 PM             29 last_update_check
-a----        3/22/2018   2:33 PM           1074 proxy-client-ca.crt
-a----        3/22/2018   2:33 PM           1675 proxy-client-ca.key
-a----        3/22/2018  10:56 PM           1103 proxy-client.crt
-a----        3/22/2018  10:56 PM           1675 proxy-client.key
```

### minikube logs

```
Mar 23 03:04:18 minikube localkube[2997]: I0323 03:04:18.212816    2997 ready.go:30] Performing healthcheck on https://localhost:8443/healthz
Mar 23 03:04:18 minikube localkube[2997]: E0323 03:04:18.219072    2997 ready.go:40] Error performing healthcheck: Get https://localhost:8443/healthz: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
Mar 23 03:04:18 minikube localkube[2997]: http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:41884: remote error: tls: bad certificate
Mar 23 03:04:19 minikube localkube[2997]: I0323 03:04:19.212786    2997 ready.go:30] Performing healthcheck on https://localhost:8443/healthz
Mar 23 03:04:19 minikube localkube[2997]: E0323 03:04:19.219637    2997 ready.go:40] Error performing healthcheck: Get https://localhost:8443/healthz: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
Mar 23 03:04:19 minikube localkube[2997]: http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:41886: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

### Certificate details

```
openssl x509 -in apiserver.crt -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 2 (0x2)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=minikubeCA
        Validity
            Not Before: Mar 23 18:05:14 2018 GMT
            Not After : Mar 23 18:05:14 2019 GMT
        Subject: O=system:masters, CN=minikube
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b5:fa:...fa:e7
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:minikubeCA, DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, DNS:kubernetes.default.svc, DNS:kubernetes.default, DNS:kubernetes, DNS:localhost, IP Address:192.168.99.100, IP Address:10.96.0.1, IP Address:10.0.0.1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         47:88:26:93:d2.....
         ab:b1:8a:43
```

Comment: What does "kubectl config current-context" report?

Comment: @JonahBenton the result is ```minikube```

Comment: I upgrade to latest version and error is still there.

Comment: When upgrading, did you also rm  -rf ~/.minikube? It is an unfortunately common cure for configuration strangeness.

Comment: i did ```minikube stop``` , remove all. Also uninstalled and reinstalled the new version. Nothing. still getting the Unauthorized message. :(

Comment: So the problem is in the little virtual machine minikube creates that runs the kubelet, apiserver, controller manager, etc. The file for this vm lives in the .minikube directory in your home directory. If you deleted the .minikube directory entirely and then created a new minikube and are still getting the issue, the options are to file a bug, or use minikube ssh to open a shell into the damaged VM and muck around with the certs directly. I have only done this a couple of times and don't have it top of mind, but there are resources describing the file system layout of a k8s master node.

Answer (score 1):

First, as reported [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2317#issuecomment-351497305) or [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2464#issuecomment-361143511), check if the issue persists in the latest version (0.25.2, which *just* got released a few hours ago)

Second, check how your certificate is formed (as [in this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2361#issuecomment-356208073))

```
openssl x509 -in apiserver.crt -text -noout
```

And/or try to [regenerate the token](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/288#issuecomment-231423876).

Comment: how do you re-generate the tokens??